# Shared storage setup for Windows

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, storage-area-network

This is a n00b question. I want to setup a SAN that will be used as shared storage between multiple Windows 2008 R2 servers. By shared storage, I mean the files can be seen by all servers. How do I do that?

Is it possible to implement this without a dedicated Windows file server? (I don't want replication).

I'm doing this so that I can setup:
http://activemq.apache.org/shared-file-system-master-slave.html

Answer (score 4):

Just buy a small NAS box, they're next to nothing these days, the sort of thing that Drobo/Netgear etc. make will do just fine.

A SAN doesn't provide access to files, but to chunks of storage space that can be mounted in the operating system like local disks. Not to mention that SANs tend to be quite costly.